# Sharing user current location react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I am working on a map and location based project currently using react native. The client has requested implementing some of ride sharing features, which I have been able to achieve. One of such feature is sharing driver current location with friend and family through a link, like it’s done in Uber and lyft. Does anyone know how this could be achieved in react native, as I am yet to fully comprehend its logic and it’s implementation.

Comment: [Real time location sharing with React Native and Socket.io](https://medium.com/@joycecyoj01/how-to-build-a-location-sharing-feature-using-react-native-and-socket-io-496413ee8065). There's a lot to find about this topic..this is just one of them. 'react-native-app-link' 'react-native-share'

Comment: Are you saying wen a user shares his own location with a friend Like it’s done on Uber, it can be achieved using socketIO?